# Windows 10: Small office network issues

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

### Introduction

Hello Superusers, Kaboom here with a bit of a pickle for you. I work in a small office that has a bunch of PC's in place running windows 10 (some pro, some home, bleh) and they have a small issue where occasionally some of them cannot see into the other ones, but those can see into them on the Network side. This is particularly problematic as we run Simply Accounting on our main host machine for connection management, our forms print off another machine, and the files are on another machine yet. I didn't set this network up originally, I have been put in charge of trying to fix it or it would be much different I assure you. First I'll explain our current setup and network.

---

### Current Setup

The following is our network path. Everything marked with a `%` tag is in the work-group `WORKGROUP`, in the network `NETWORK 2` and are all in the same Home-group for file-sharing as well as have their `C:/` drives mapped to the network with 20 concurrent users set. The IP's aren't exact or anything but it should give you a pretty good idea of the system setup:

```
External Internet Connection (4 separate bridged IP's)
↳ Customer Wifi Network (Own AP) (172.x.x.x) [NOT LINKED IN ANY WAY]
↳ Store network AP Router (Static IP) (172.x.x.x)
  ↳ Modem with static bridged to first 2 ports (192.168.10.1)
    ↳ Camera System (192.168.10.2)
    ↳ Web Server & Simply Connection Manager (192.168.10.3 / 192.168.1.2) %
    ↳ Modem for DHCP clients and office connections (192.168.10.4 / 192.168.1.1)
      ↳ LAN Switch
        ↳ IP Based time punch clock (192.168.1.3)
        ↳ Seagate-D2 Storage server (192.168.1.4 / [\\Seagate-d2])
        ↳ IRLP Internet radio (192.168.1.5) (Linux radio system)
        ↳ Ethernet radio repeater system (192.168.1.6)
        ↳ Win 10 Pro PC (192.168.1.7 / [\\Sales-1]) - Has Simply Files %
        ↳ Win 10 Pro PC (192.168.1.8 / [\\Sales-2]) - Has Simply Print  forms %
        ↳ Win 10 Pro PC (192.168.1.9 / [\\Office-Acc]) %
        ↳ Win 10 Home PC (192.168.1.10 / [\\Accounting-Acc]) %
        ↳ Win 10 Home PC (192.168.1.11 / [\\Service-Acc]) %
        ↳ Win 10 Pro PC (192.168.1.12 / [\\Sales-3]) %
```

---

### Issues with this system

This setup has worked perfectly for the last few months. It had a similar connection issue before; but after a lot of time configuring shares and network names and Home-groups we were able to make them all talk and work together without incident for months. Last week our internet provider switched everything over to a new fiber-optic system and it seems like the computers all lost their brains and refuse to connect sometimes, but not all the times, and while some computers (using the network share options on the side of file explorer) can see and browse all the PC's, others can't see into the ones that are looking into them. 3 PC's have no issue seeing everyone, 2 can see most of them, and the Office one has issues seeing anything but the server and sales-1. The networks are private, Home-group is there, all the settings are the same, the `OPENFILES` command and `NET SESSIONS` aren't showing any connections on most of them yet it's saying permission is denied but only sometimes.

---

### Solutions?

If I had a server with Windows Server on it I am aware that I could add a domain group and then they shouldn't have this issue but that option doesn't work for me right now. I would run them all to the Seagate-d2 storage device, but some programs like Simply need a processor to run the Connection Manager so that's not plausible either since the Seagate-d2 cannot run programs at all. This system has been in place long before I started and I can't just change them all over to Windows Enterprise editions either as that would fix it too. What options are there? What suggestions do you have as to how this connection denied problem can be avoided? There is a lot of Google questions but not a lot of answers so hopefully we can find one that works for me as I'm sure many others are having this issue too.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You couldn’t connect Windows 10 Home to an AD domain even if you had Windows Server.

Comment: I don't understand your network description. Especially why some devices have multiple IP addresses. Can you better explain the setup or add a picture instead of how things are actually connected? Did the ISP change any modems? Specifically the one you say is for DHCP clients and office connections? This could be a NetBIOS / DNS issue. For kicks can you disable IPv6 on one or more problematic machines and test? Do you have any trouble accessing the machines by IP address?